# 401k age 55 rule question

Tags: united-states, 401k, employment

I just want somebody to clarify this for me. The way I read it is you qualify if you leave your job that you have the 401k in the year that you turn 55. So if I turn 55 on September 1, 2017 but I leave on January 1, 2017, then I still qualify. Is this correct?

Comment: [Age 55 rule](https://www.irahelp.com/slottreport/age-55-rule-taking-money-out-company-retirement-plan).  For anyone else who doesn't know about this.

Answer (score 1):

> It’s the year someone separates from service that matters, not the
>   distribution date. To qualify for the penalty exception, separation
>   from service must occur in the year the person turns age 55 or older.

From the [Ed Slott article](https://www.irahelp.com/slottreport/age-55-rule-taking-money-out-company-retirement-plan) linked in the comment.

Yes, if you leave in the year you turn 55, you're all set.

The option if you miss the date is a [Sec 72(t)](http://www.joetaxpayer.com/section-72t-withdrawals/) series of withdrawals.